# Get SharePoint folders and docs using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to get the folders and documents from a SharePoint document library using Microsoft Graph API.

If I do a `GET` request for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/MyDocumentSite:/drives/`, I get this back:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value":[
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2019-09-05T07:09:49Z",
            "description": "",
            "id": "b!wxh2ZWwoT0KKTdLRYjD5jvzjo8jkat5LgY3VyfgEqkv3YVg_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-09-05T07:09:49Z",
            "name": "Documents",
            "webUrl": "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/MyDocumentSite/Shared%20Documents",
            "driveType": "documentLibrary",
            "createdBy":{"user":{"displayName": "System Account" }},
            "lastModifiedBy":{"user":{"email": "me@myorganization.org", "id": "73f9990c-5c92-4839-8b13-XXXXXXXXXXXX", "displayName": "John Smith"…},
            "quota":{"deleted": 0, "remaining": 0, "total": 0, "used": 0}
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I try to access that drive by doing a `GET` request on that id: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/MyDocumentSite:/drives/b!wxh2ZWwoT0KKTdLRYjD5jvzjo8jkat5LgY3VyfgEqkv3YVg_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`, I get a BadRequest error:

```
{
    "error":{
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Url specified is invalid.",
        "innerError":{
            "request-id": "7c9eaf61-764f-4d72-abdb-ffa2fe868e90",
            "date": "2019-09-16T19:09:41"
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I want a way to display all folders and documents from the document library but I can't seem to get past this initial step.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, when site is addressed by [site path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getbypath?view=graph-rest-1.0), the following query fails with the exception:

```
GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/{server-relative-path}/drive/root/children`
```

It appears to be a *bug* since the similar query but when site is [addressed by id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), is working as expected:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root/children
```

Another option to consider, to get `Drive` resource by its identifier (without specifying site path or identifier), for example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/children
```

---

When it comes the turn of getting *all* the documents and folder within a library, [`List children of a driveItem` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) returns only 1 level beneath the current folder.

To return all the drive items, you could at least consider to:

- utilize [`search` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http),for example `GET
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='')`
- recursively traverse folder structure via [`List children of a driveItem` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "delta" API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The first call will return all the items. (If there is pagination you'll need to call nextLink, until you receive a deltaLink).

You will probably want to use one either
`GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/root/delta`
or
`GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/delta`

Comment: That only seems to work for the default drive on the global site, not the sub-site that my document library lives on. See my URLs in the question.

Comment: Notice in the URLs in the original question, I'm using /sites/{site-url}:/{subsite-path}:/drives to get my drive list.

Comment: Should work fine if you use the drive id (without the site id) + delta.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the drive id you want to query, use /drives at the root to make your request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveId>
```